# AudioKit - Play sound files at specific position using sequencer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I'd like to use the AudioKit framework to generate a small sound sequence of some high and low sounds.

So what I'm starting with is the message that could look like this: "`1100011010`"

--> Every column should be looped through and if it's value is `"1"` AudioKit should play a (short) `high frequency` sound and if not it should play a (short) `lower frequency` sound.

Because a **simple timer-loop  that triggers every 0.15s** the `.play()`-function for running a **0.1s sound (high/low)** doesn't seems to be very accurate I decided to use the **`*AudioKit Sequencer*`**:

(o) audiokit:

```
enum Sequence: Int {
    case snareDrum
}
var snareDrum = AKSynthSnare()
var sequencer = AKSequencer()
var pumper: AKCompressor?
var mixer = AKMixer()

public init() {
    snareDrum >>> mixer
    pumper = AKCompressor(mixer)

    AudioKit.output = pumper
    AudioKit.start()
}

func setupTracks() {
    _ = sequencer.newTrack()
    sequencer.tracks[Sequence.snareDrum.rawValue].setMIDIOutput(snareDrum.midiIn)
    generateMessageSequence()

    sequencer.enableLooping()
    sequencer.setTempo(2000)
    sequencer.play()
}
```

---

(o) play:
    var message="1100011010"
    var counter=0

```
for i in message {
  counter+=0.15
  if (i=="1") {
   // play high sound at specific position 
  }
  else {
   // play low sound at specific position
  } 
}
```

---

(o) play low sound at specific position:

```
 sequencer.tracks[Sequence.snareDrum.rawValue].add(noteNumber: 20,
                                                   velocity: 10,
                                                   position: AKDuration(beats: counter),
                                                   duration: AKDuration(beats: 1))
```

---

**My question**: How is it possible to play local sound files at specific positions using `(position: AKDuration(beats: counter)) //the code from above` instead of using default instruments like in this case `AKSynthSnare()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create two tracks, each with an AKMIDISampler. One plays a 'low' sample, and the other plays a 'high' sample. Assign the high notes to the high track, and low notes to the low track.

```
let sequencer = AKSequencer()
let lowTrack = sequencer.newTrack()
let lowSampler = AKMIDISampler()
try! lowSampler.loadWav("myLowSoundFile")
lowTrack?.setMIDIOutput(lowSampler.midiIn)

let highTrack = sequencer.newTrack()
let highSampler = AKMIDISampler()
try! highSampler.loadWav("myHighSoundFile")
highTrack?.setMIDIOutput(highSampler.midiIn)

sequencer.setLength(AKDuration(beats: 4.0))
sequencer.enableLooping()
```

then assign the high and low sounds to each track

```
let message = "1100011010"
let dur = 4.0 / Double(message.count)
var position: Double = 0
for i in message {
  position += dur

  if (i == "1") {
   highTrack?.add(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100, position: AKDuration(beats: position), duration: AKDuration(beats: dur * (2/3)))
  } else {
   lowTrack?.add(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100, position: AKDuration(beats: position), duration: AKDuration(beats: dur * (2/34)))
  } 
}
```

(I haven't run the code, but something like this should work)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer c_booth. Your code looks absolutely fine and logical - But using your code  produces this error message: `[seq] 1026: Invalid beat range
CheckError.swift:CheckError:78:Error: kMIDINotPermitted: Have you enabled the audio background mode in your ios app?`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Enable background audio in the "Capabilities" tab for your project, under "Background Modes."

Comment: Thanks Aurelius - the kMIDI-error was successfully removed but I still get this `[seq] 1026: Invalid beat range` error. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You'll see that message every time you make a new track with the sequencer, but it's not an error message and everything should work fine in spite of it.  I think I read in the AudioKit Google Group that it's coming from somewhere in CoreAudio.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information c_booth. I will try to run the code again later but when I‘ve tested it 2 hours ago I wasn‘t be able to hear any sound. Anyway thanks for helping me out, I will mark your answer as correct after testing again! :)